# Java - Deleting certain lines from a file

Tags: java, line, filereader

I'm trying to delete certain lines from a file. My file is a .txt and it looks like this:

```
    [ITEMS]

    [BANK]

    [FRIENDS]

    [EOF]
```

As my program runs, it writes lines in this file. Now what I want to do is have a method, that when I call it, it will delete all the lines **in between** [BANK] and [FRIENDS]. It can't delete anything else. Leaving one empty line.

If you need more info, let me know!

Comment: Could you please post the code you're trying? Precisely [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Create temp file, rewrite original file to the new one without unnecessary lines, replace original one with a new one

Comment: Post some code and we can help.  One approach would be to open a new "tmp" file, the 'source' file above, and start reading lines from the source file and writing them to the tmp file.  When you get to the section you don't want in the tmp file, skip writing those lines.  Than start again when you get to the `[FRIENDS]` tag.  When you're done, rename the first file to whatever.archive (etc) and rename the tmp file to what the source was was originally called.

Comment: I have no idea where to start, the lines are never the same and I can't just replace the file while it's in use. It's not homework, it's a character file. While the player is logged in, if I were to just delete the file lots of things would go wrong.

Comment: Ok, we can get you going, but this site isn't a "do it for me" site. It's a site about good questions and _peer-reviewed_ answers.  For us to give you a good answer, you have to put forth an effort to solve the problem.  So, let me ask: do you know how to open a file, read all the lines, displaying them to the screen as you do?

Comment: I made a FileUtil class that reads, writes, removes lines/strings from files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partly finished code, to show you the idea what has to be done, but it may have some flaws, it uses Google Guava - http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.io.Files;

public class LinesDeleter {
    private static boolean between;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("somePath");
        deleteLinesBetweenFromFile("line1", "line2", file);

    }

    private static void deleteLinesBetweenFromFile(String start, String end,
            File file) throws IOException {
        List<String> readLines = null;
        List<String> newLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();

        readLines = Files.readLines(file, charset);

        if (readLines != null) {
            for (String line : readLines)
                if ( !isBetweenBannedLines(line, start, end))
                    newLines.add(line);
            File to = new File("somefile");
            Files.write(writeAsSingleLines(newLines), to, charset);
        }

    }

    private static CharSequence writeAsSingleLines(List<String> newLines) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isBetweenBannedLines(String line, String start,
            String end) {
        if (line.equals(start)) {
            between = true;
            return true;
        }
        if (line.equals(end)) {
            between = false;
            return true;
        }
        if (between)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do (if you haven't already done already) is have some in-file marker of recognizing when a field, such as [BANK] or [FRIENDS], has started or ended.  If you format your file like this:

```
#Start Bank Section
<some bank data>
<some more bank data>
#End Bank Section
<junk you want to get rid of>
<more junk you want to get rid of>
<even more junk you want to get rid of>
#Start Friends Section
...
```

Then you can write a function for reading in each section and converting it to a String, which you can then output to the new or overwritten file as necessary.

If you don't have control over how the file is formatted, you will need some way of distinguishing between lines, which will require more detailed information about how your file is formatted in the first place.

If you need to put anything (like an empty line) between the Bank and Friends section, you can do that very easily by just writing a string consisting of the newline character ("\n") to the file in between writing the Bank and Friend sections to file.